# How to determine the empty Logical_data_block for a table

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Lets say my table have 1 segment with 1 extent in it.

If you query

```
SELECT BLOCKS 
FROM DBA_EXTENTS 
WHERE owner LIKE 'owner' 
  AND segment_name LIKE 'segmentname';
```

You can get back the amount of logical blocks that an extent is storing.

How can you determine from this (for example) 8 block which one is actually used and which one is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if anyone ever needs this you can get the amount of empty logical blocks by

1. Summing the non empty blocks
   `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM( SELECT DBMS_ROWID.ROWID_BLOCK_NUMBER(rowid) FROM yourtable GROUP BY DBMS_ROWID.ROWID_BLOCK_NUMBER(ROWID))`
2. Getting the amount of all blocks `SELECT SUM(BLOCKS) FROM dba_segments WHERE owner LIKE ownerofyourtable AND segment_name LIKE nameofyourtable'`
3. Then you have to just subtract the 2. I did it in pl/sql but I assume from this point it should be easy enough.

Care for the UPPER and LOWER case in the second point.